# Xml Validation - XSD 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

Is it possible in XSD 1.0 to set that maxOccurs should be fixed for all elements? Example:

```
<row>
  <tile />
  <tile />
</row>
```

Then if I want to create a new row, it has to have exactly 2 tiles. So it should look like this:

```
<row>
  <tile />
  <tile />
</row>
<row>
  <tile />
  <tile />
</row>
```

However, I want the amount tiles you can make unbounded. But it is locked to the count on first row. So if there are 5 tiles in the first row, it there must be exactly 5 tiles in all the other rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD 1.1 you can put an assertion on whatever element is the parent of the rows, to say they must all have the same number of tiles:

```
<xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(row/count(tile))) = 1"/>
```

But you can't do this kind of thing in XSD 1.0.

Comment: For some reason I cannot use XSD 1.1. However someone named using a Schematron, is it possible to apply what you just did using that?

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible to do this using Schematron but I'm not the person to help you with that. (And please make some attempt to find out the answer for yourself before asking here!)

Answer (score 0):

No, to my knowledge that is not possible. In the next version of XSD (1.1) you can by adding Schematron rules.

As an alternative, consider doing a two-pass validation: First pass it through your schema. After that do a second pass using Schematron. In Schematron you can check these kinds of things.

Comment: How can I used the 'Schematron' to do what I would like to do?